# codeigniter bootstrap modal popup

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap modal popup in my site. By clicking the button pop will open. It is working on the following code.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

But the button come from array.

```
<?php   
   $args['test'] = array(
      array(
      'type'    => 'submit',
      'id'      => ' text',
      'label'   => 'Launch demo modal',
      'desc'    => site_url('test'),
      'class'   => 'span3',
      'default' => '',
      'options' => ''),
   );

?>
```

How can I pass `"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing different, just add those attributes in the array like this:

```
array(
    'type'    => 'submit',
    'id'      => ' musicfileupload',
    'label'   => 'Launch demo modal',
    'desc'    => site_url('test'),
    'class'   => 'span3',
    'default' => '',
    'options' => '',
    'data-toggle' => 'modal', // <--
    'data-target' => '#myModal' // <--
);
```

**Update:** Following is a working example:

```
$data = array(
    'type'    => 'submit',
    'id'      => ' musicfileupload',
    'label'   => 'Launch demo modal',
    'desc'    => site_url('test'),
    'class'   => 'span3',
    'default' => '',
    'options' => '',
    'data-toggle' => 'modal', // <--
    'data-target' => '#myModal' // <--
);
echo form_button($data);
```